# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization expected START_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

I need to deserializa a Json like this:

```
{  
   "arrayObj1":[  
      {  
         "type":"t1",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "value1":"a"
            },
            {  
               "value2":"b"
            }
         ],
         "otherInfo":"abc"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thats how i try to do it:

```
public class ClassA{
private ArrayObj1[] arrayObj1;}
```

Then...

```
    public class ArrayObj1 extends Value{
    private String type;
    private Value [] value;

 @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
                  property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes(value={
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = T1.class, name = "t1")
    })
    public void setValue (Value [] value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and...

```
public abstract class Value {}
```

This is the error iv got:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class ... etc

How to handle this? Thanks.

EDIT: This is how i deserialize:

```
public ClassA getObj (String jsonString) {
    ClassA obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, ClassA.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Full error is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token
>   (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain
>   As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class .Value  at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@4317b868; line: 1, column: 496] (through
>   reference chain: .ClassA["arrayObj1"]->.ArrayObj1["value"])

Comment: What code are you using to actually do the deserialisation? And what is the full error message? These things will help to debug your issue.

Comment: Hi, im not sure about it, but this is how i deserialize, i edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure you use, you actually need one more level of classes to contain external type id. So something like this:

```
public class ClassA {
  private ValueWrapper[] arrayObj1;
}

public class ValueWrapper {
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
              property = "type")
  @JsonSubTypes(value={
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = T1.class, name = "t1")
  }
  public Value value;

  public String otherInfo;

  // or use getters/setters in addition; left as fields for brevity
}

public abstract class Value { ... }
```

)

However, looking at your JSON more closely, this actually would only work if your values were POJOs. If assumption is that type is for all elements of the `value` array, there is no automated way to do that.
You will unfortunately need to handle polymorphic types manually.

Comment: So, if the value array is an array of POJOs, all from the same "type" i could not handle it with jackson?

Comment: Short answer is no, you can not use `@JsonTypeInfo` the way JSON is structured. `type` would have to be for each and every value, and NOT for array.